# Изменить цвет границ ячеек DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Есть `DataGridView`. Подскажите, возможно ли изменить цвет границы всех ячеек? К примеру, сделать зеленым.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я Вас понял, то Вам нужно зайти в свойства Вашего `DataGridView` и найти там свойство `GridColor`, поставить там нужный цвет и получите нужный цвет сетки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Свойство `DataGridView.GridColor` - получает или задает цвет линий
>   сетки, разделяющих ячейки объекта `DataGridView`.

Набросал пример, добавил три колонки и несколько строк, а потом изменил цвет сетки на почти зеленый - лайм (p.s. просто `Color.Green` темноват по-моему), чтобы наглядно было видно эффект:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Либо можете сделать это с помощью кода, к примеру внутри конструктора формы:

```
dataGridView1.GridColor = Color.Green;
```

Список полезных ссылок для ознакомления:

1. [Свойство DataGridView.GridColor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.gridcolor(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. [How to: Change the Border and Gridline Styles in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ehz9ksfa(v=vs.110).aspx)